# Where (in which file) does Eclipse store database drivers definitions?

Tags: database, eclipse, configuration, driver

I'm trying to control mutliple Eclipse configurations through SVN. For that purpose I need to know in which files does Eclipse store his configurations. What I could not find, is where are the driver definitions stored (I mean the stuff which is set up at Preferences->Data Management->Connectivity->Driver Definitions). Does anybody know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are stored at `<Workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity`.